# Implementing Long press on Text Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a `LazyColumn` of `Text()`. I've set clickable for `Text()` but it's equivalent to `OnClickListner`. Now I want to set an equivalent of `setOnLongClickListener`. How can I do that?

```
@Composable
fun MyText(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

  var isSelected by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
        Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
                .clickable { isSelected = !isSelected }
                .padding(16.dp)
        )
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [**`combinedClickable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary.html#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).combinedClickable(kotlin.Boolean,%20kotlin.String,%20androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,%20kotlin.String,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0)) modifier to get the different click events:

```
Text(
    text = text,
    modifier = Modifier
        .combinedClickable(
            onLongClick = { /*....*/ },
            onClick ={ /*....*/ })
        .padding(16.dp)
)
```

Notice that it is an `@ExperimentalFoundationApi` feature and is likely to change or be removed in the future.

Comment: That's experimental right?
This foundation API is experimental and is likely to change or be removed in the future. `@ExperimentalFoundationApi`

Comment: @TinaTT2 Yes, it can change, like many others in the current 1.0.0